# When using the sticky footer trick for my site, one of the lines in my footer is off center

Tags: html, css

I was trying to set up a footer for my site, and one of the lines of text became off-centre. I don't understand how this happened, but I know this wasn't happening on any other page of my site with the sticky footer, and it doesn't happen when I remove the <div class="page-wrap> tag for the body.

The only thing that's too big of a difference between this page of the site and any other is that I was using two iframes to play video. Everything else, including the page layout, was basically the same. The only other possibility I could think of was a typo and I couldn't find one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  <DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
      <title>Title</title>
      <style>
        .topnav {
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: black;
          display:flex;
        }

        .topnav a {
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        .topnav a:first-child {
          font-weight: 700;
        }
        .topnav a:hover {
          background-color: #151515;
          font-weight: 700;
        }
        .topnav a:before {
          display: block;
          content: attr(data-title);
          font-weight: 700;
          overflow: hidden;
          visibility: hidden;
          height: 0;
        }
        .footer {
          background-color: black;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 10px;
          margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        .center {
          text-align: center;
        }
        .column {
          float: left;
          padding: 10px;
        }
        .column.side {
          width: 25%;
        }
        .column.middle {
          width: 50%;
        }
        .row:after {
          content: "";
          display: table;
          clear: both;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
          .column.side, .column.middle {
            width: 100%;
          }
        }
        body {
          height: 100%;
        }
        .page-wrap {
          min-height: 100%;
          margin-bottom: -142px;
        }
        .page-wrap:after {
          content: "";
          display: block;
        }
        .footer, .page-wrape:after {
          height: 142px;
        }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page-wrap">
      <h>heading<h>
      <div class="topnav">
        <a data-title="Home" href="\index.html">Home</a>
        <a data-title="Page 2" href="\Page2\index.html">Coming Soon</a>
        <a data-title="Page 3" href="\Page3\index.html">Video Library</a>
        <a data-title="Page 4" href="\Page4\index.html">Cast and Crew</a>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column side">
          <p>side column contents</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column middle">
          <p>middle column contents</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column side">
          <p>side column contents</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <p>This line is not centered</p>
        <p>This line is centered</p>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: `position: center;` is not valid CSS. [Position documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: As @DBS has mentioned `position: center` is invalid, you want `text-align: center`

Comment: I already removed it. However, thank you for letting me know. @akaBase

Answer (score 0):

Grids will make your life a whole lot easier. Based on the grid solution from [this article](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/).

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
}
footer {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.topnav {
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: black;
          display:flex;
        }
        .topnav a {
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        .topnav a:first-child {
          font-weight: 700;
        }
        .topnav a:hover {
          background-color: #151515;
          font-weight: 700;
        }
        .topnav a:before {
          display: block;
          content: attr(data-title);
          font-weight: 700;
          overflow: hidden;
          visibility: hidden;
          height: 0;
        }
        .row {
          display: grid;
        }
        .row>*:nth-child(1) {
          background-color: yellow;
        }
        .row>*:nth-child(2) {
          background-color: cyan;
        }
        .row>*:nth-child(3) {
          background-color: lime;
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
          .row {
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
          }
        }
        footer {
          color: white;
          background-color: black;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="page-wrap">
      <h1>heading</h1>
      <div class="topnav">
        <a data-title="Home" href="\index.html">Home</a>
        <a data-title="Page 2" href="\Page2\index.html">Coming Soon</a>
        <a data-title="Page 3" href="\Page3\index.html">Video Library</a>
        <a data-title="Page 4" href="\Page4\index.html">Cast and Crew</a>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div>
          <p>side column contents</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>middle column contents</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <p>side column contents</div>
        </div>
      </div>
 </div>
 <footer>
   <p>This line is centered</p>
   <p>This line is centered</p>
 </footer>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fix your HTML code (i.e. the superfluous `</div>` and unclosed `h` tags), then your css will apply and everything will work as expected:

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
      .topnav {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: black;
        display: flex;
      }
      
      .topnav a {
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      
      .topnav a:first-child {
        font-weight: 700;
      }
      
      .topnav a:hover {
        background-color: #151515;
        font-weight: 700;
      }
      
      .topnav a:before {
        display: block;
        content: attr(data-title);
        font-weight: 700;
        overflow: hidden;
        visibility: hidden;
        height: 0;
      }
      
      .footer {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
      }
      
      .center {
        text-align: center;
      }
      
      .column {
        float: left;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      
      .column.side {
        width: 25%;
      }
      
      .column.middle {
        width: 50%;
      }
      
      .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
      }
      
      @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .column.side,
        .column.middle {
          width: 100%;
        }
      }
      
      body {
        height: 100%;
      }
      
      .page-wrap {
        min-height: 100%;
        margin-bottom: -142px;
      }
      
      .page-wrap:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
      }
      
      .footer,
      .page-wrape:after {
        height: 142px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="page-wrap">
      <div class="topnav">
        <a data-title="Home" href="\index.html">Home</a>
        <a data-title="Page 2" href="\Page2\index.html">Coming Soon</a>
        <a data-title="Page 3" href="\Page3\index.html">Video Library</a>
        <a data-title="Page 4" href="\Page4\index.html">Cast and Crew</a>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="column side">
          <p>side column contents</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column middle">
          <p>middle column contents</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column side">
          <p>side column contents</div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <p>This line is not centered</p>
        <p>This line is centered</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```